# Query element in nested shadow root

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

**Scenerio**: 
In my application I have nested **shadow-roots**, and I want to get an element in the **inner shadow-root** from outer **shadow-root**.

What I actually mean is that consider this scenerio.

```
<Component 1 id="headerComponent">
#shadow-root // outer shadow-root.
  <div class="header"></div> // element in outer shadow-root.
  #shadow-root // inner shadow-root.
    <Component 2 id="titleComponent"> // We have component 2 inside the shadow root of component 1.
       <input class="titleInput"> // element inside inner shadow-root.
```

Now, If I am in `Component 1.js` and want to Query any element in `Component 1.js`, I will write this block of code `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.header');`, and it works well.

But, If I am in `Component 1.js` and want to Query an element(*here it is `<input>` with class **titleInput***) in `Component 2.js`, How can I do it?

Trying the similar statement like `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.titleInput');` doesn't seems to work and returns `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
Here is the snippet of js that will do the magic.

```
this.$.titleComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('.input-wrap');
```

For those who are not familier with polymer architecture.

Here, As I am in `Component 1`.
So, `this` refers to component 1(Component 1 class methods, properties and this.$ is used to select elements inside Component 1 class template having the id followed by this.$.elementID), `this.$.titleComponent` selects **titleComponent** and this statement selects the  element `shadowRoot.querySelector('.input-wrap')`.